# Client jar file version for IBM MQ7 and MQ8

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, websphere-liberty, ibm-jre

Our product will support IBM MQ7 and MQ8 based on client requirement. Now, we like to know latest client jar version that we may use for our application?

We would like to use JMS 1.1 specification. I have found following link for MQ 7.5 JAR-
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q120070_.htm

Is it sufficient if we use above mentioned client jar to connect MQ 7 and MQ 8 server?

Application will use **JRE 1.7** and **WAS liberty 8.5.5.9**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WebSphere Liberty as your application server, then you will need to the MQ JCA Resource Adapter (MQ-RA) to make use of MQ JMS messaging.  Liberty (unlike traditional WebSphere Application Server) does not ship a copy of the MQ-RA, but you can download and install one pretty easily and then link to it from within the Liberty server's server.xml configuration file.  Here's a link to explain how to do this:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21633761

Now, Liberty can use a copy of the WebSphere MQ V7.5.0.5 (or later) Resource Adapter, which only supports the JMS 1.1 API, and the Liberty feature you will want to enable with that version is "wmqJmsClient-1.1".

However, I would suggest you consider the latest version of the IBM MQ-RA (at the time of writing this is V9.0.0.0).  The MQ V8.0.0.3 and V9 RAs support both the JMS 1.1 "classic" API as well as the newer 2.0 "simplified" API.  Therefore you can use the newer MQ-RA levels but your JMS 1.1 application will still work perfectly fine.  If using a V8 or V9 IBM MQ-RA, then the Liberty feature to enable to is "wmqJmsClient-2.0".

The V7.5, V8 and V9 MQ Resource Adapters can connect to **any** MQ queue manager version; the major or maintenance versions between the JMS client and the MQ server do not need to match.

For reference, here are a couple of links I recommend reading over as well:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031610_.htm

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_dep_msg_wmq.html

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/rwlp_restrict.html

I hope this helps!